# Is $\mathbb R$ of second category in itself?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

I stumbled over the question

> Is the closure of a set of first category also of first category?

and immediately thought of $\overline{\mathbb Q}  = \mathbb R$ as a counterexample. Clearly, $\mathbb Q$ is of first category. But is $\mathbb R$? I highly assume it is not, but it doesn't seem to be as obvious as I thought. Any simple proofs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space with respect to the usual topology,so from Baire's theorem is of second category in itself.

A set of second category is a set which is not of first category,i.e it cannot be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets.

So your counterexample is valid.

Also remember that Baire's theorem has this corollary:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $F_n$ a countable collection of closed sets ,such that $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$
>
> Then at least one of these closed sets $F_n$ has a nonempty interior.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the proof would look like: "If $\mathbb R$ was a countable union of nowhere dense sets $A_n$, $\mathbb R$ would be nowhere dense as well, which is a contradiction."?

Comment: @lappen68...No...A union  of nowhere desne sets is not nowhere dense..for instance take the rationals...but $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space so satisfies Baire's theorem thus it cannot be of second category.

Comment: Screw me, I confused "nowhere dense" with "has empty interior". Then the argument should work. In my script this is a corollary of Baire's theorem. Thank you very much! Edit: Well, actually my first argument should work, but obviously only because $\mathbb R$ is complete, while $Q$ is not. I just didn't mention the usage of the Baire theorem.

Comment: Excuse me but I still don't understand how we can imply R is of second category.